# Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using below code to set root view controller. But It is giving me error:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"SignUp", bundle:nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UIViewController
    self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
```

I am getting error like `Downcast from 'UIViewController?' to 'UIViewController' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?`

I think, It has to do with "`as!`", but it is introduced in new swift.

Does any one have idea ?

Comment: The code you have written, is working good. Yes, you have to put "!"

Comment: But where I will have to put "!" ?

Comment: Yeah thats the correct way below!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to do this I suppose

Safer one:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"SignUp", bundle:nil)
 if let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController(){
    self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
 }
```

edit:  removed `as? UIViewController`

The one suggested by the compiler:

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name:"SignUp", bundle:nil)
 let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
 self.window!.rootViewController = viewController
```

Basically the compiler is just letting you know that the `as! UIViewController` in this code is basically just the same as using one `!`

Comment: There's no need for `as? UIViewController` in the first example. That's the return type; you can just drop it.